# Are Outlook MSG/OFT templates dynamic or statically generated?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, templates

"Common sense-wise" I don't see why the contacts referenced in a contact group would be statically contained within the actual .msg file.

So my question is, if I create a .msg template with a contact group as a recipient, is that contact group saved inside the .msg or are they just references to the actual contact group that resides in the address book for the given mailbox?

I want to know if I can use the same .msg even when the contact group contains other contacts than when I created the template.

If it is indeed static, is there a way to make it dynamic using Developer Tools in Outlook 2016? I am fine using .OFT files as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried out this in my Outlook , but it seems that only the reference group is saved in the .msg file which is saved and it will be referred only during sending your actual message as it is not a clever idea to store all the recipient information in the .msg file because of the filesize optimization issues.

So , if you create a contact group and save the .msg , every time you open the template, only current members of the message group will be referred rather than the one which was there during saving the .msg.

I tested it by creating a sample group with mem1 , mem2 and created a message and saved it. I deleted the member mem2 from the group and saved it as another message. When I opened first .msg file which had 2 contacts in the group while saving , was showing only one member in the group which is the updated version of the group.

Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: Well, that would be exactly what I want. As this is a business critical operation, it would need to contain the current members of the group, which, reading your answer, it seems this is the case? thanks a lot.

Comment: In that case , outlook has already read your mind to give what you want.

Comment: Sweet! A manager was doubting this, but I should be able to convince him now.

Comment: Cool, maybe you can demonstrate the same thing which I did in the example , in your PC.

Comment: For posterity, and all that: The manager has successfully been convinced.

Comment: Good to know!! :)